# VSCode Compiled Extension Doesn't Recognize Extension Commands

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on a VS Code extension. What it generally does is read data from some JSON files and presents that data in a custom viewsContainer.

My extension doesn't seem to run into any issues when compiled to VSIX, however, all of the commands I've defined in the package.json are not recognized once the extension is installed.

However, once I've installed my extension and restarted VS Code, click the icon for my view container, and try clicking any of the buttons I've mapped to commands in my source code, every item returns `command <commandname> not found`

I keep getting a warning saying that I should use webpack, and that several hundreds of files are included.

In my source, and resources folders, I have a grand total of 32 files, and in the remaining root I have 8 other files (.gitignore, etc defaults)

I'm excluding `node_modules` in my tsconfig.json, so not sure where the rest of the files are coming from or if its just dev dependencies.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to remove `node_modules` from the `exclude: []` section of my .tsconfig
Everything worked fine after that.

Run an `npm install` in your extension project directory first, then `vsce package`
To check what gets packaged, run `vsce ls`

Comment: I also needed to upgrade the compiler version, `npm -i typescript -g` and remove the TypeScript SDK path from my system Path variable. Because... Windows